# I am an Indian passport holder. Can I get a transit visa in Seoul if I am traveling to Australia with a valid tourist visa?

Tags: transit-visas

I am planning to travel from India to Australia with a tourist visa. I would like to visit South Korea during the trip. I want to know if I can get a transit at Seoul for some days.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes you can**, and you can stay for up to 30 days.

> **Transit Visa (General) B-2-1**
>   If you satisfy any of the following conditions, you can travel to or transit through Korea without a visa. You will be able to stay for up to 30 days in Korea.
>
> 1) Frequent Visitors : You have entered Korea at least 4 times within the past 2 years, or 10 times in your total travel history. Also, you have never violated Korean laws or overstayed in Korea before.
>
> 2) Transit Tourists Travelling to a Third Country 
>   - You transit through Korea on your way to the United States, Canada, Australia, and New Zealand and hold a valid visa (including re-entry permit) issued by the aforementioned countries. 
>   - You transit through Korea on your way to a third country or the country of nationality via direct flight from the United States, Canada, Australia, and New Zealand to Korea after legally staying in these respective countries.

Source: [Korea Visa Portal](https://www.visa.go.kr/openPage.do?MENU_ID=10101)

Comment: Note that Australia [only issues label-free e-visas](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa/visa) so you would not be able transit Korea under the first dot point.

Comment: @k2moo4 Official visa portal, which i have updated the link to, does not seem to require that to be a strictly sticker visa